# wget to retrieve search results from virustotal

Tags: bash, curl, wget

I am trying to retrieve the search results from virustotal for ransomware keyword, where I am trying to use the following code:

```
 wget "https://www.virustotal.com/#/search/ransomware" -O output.txt
```

However, I do not get the result output. I am expecting to get at least the hash value of each resulted sample, where I am planning to use them later on.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either curl or wget to do this.

**Using Curl**

```
curl 'https://www.virustotal.com/ui/search?query=ransomware&relationships\[url\]=network_location%2Clast_serving_ip_address&relationships\[comment\]=author%2Citem' -H 'pragma: no-cache' -H 'cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1407677727.1526818525; _gid=GA1.2.163855722.1526818525; _gat=1' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36' -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'authority: www.virustotal.com' -H 'referer: https://www.virustotal.com/' --compressed
```

**Using wget**

```
wget 'https://www.virustotal.com/ui/search?query=ransomware&relationships\[url\]=network_location%2Clast_serving_ip_address&relationships\[comment\]=author%2Citem' -O output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! But this does not extract all the results, there is more tabs that loads more results. Not sure if it is feasible with curl or wget

Comment: it is possible to load all other tabs, but those will be different requests. But did this at least give you some data which you were not able to get with your wget request in the question?

Comment: Indeed it does, but not all the results

Comment: yes, you can do that, if you see the response to the first request, it has the link for loading more results. you have to capture that and fire the subsequent request to load more result. If this helped you to solve the problem accept this answer and upvote